# Visual Studio 2012 won't let me debug Implementation of Interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I was going through some of the queries in LINQ and wanted to understand its implementation, so i thought of debugging the same but when i tried to do it Visual Studio is not entering into the implementation of the interface don't know why is it. I am using Visual Studio Community 2015. Here is my code

```
class Client
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] words = { "aPPLE", "AbAcUs", "bRaNcH", "BlUeBeRrY", "ClOvEr", "cHeRry" };
            var result = words.OrderBy(a => a, new CaseInsensitiveComparer());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    public class CaseInsensitiveComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("x is " + x + " & y is " + y+" the value is "+ string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            return string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
    }
```

and the saddest part is i am also not able to print anything in my console window

> Console.WriteLine("x is " + x + " & y is " + y+" the value is "+
>   string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

I understand there are many duplicate questions regarding this but i tried everything and none of them  worked for me.

1. I tried cleaning the solution
2. Delete Obj and Bin folder
3. close the solution and open it again and rebuild it
   Nothing worked for me.

**UPDATE 1**

I have placed my debugger inside the implementation of the IComparer
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `.OrderBy()` call will only be evaluated when you use its result (as is the case with a lot of the linq methods). As you aren't using the result, the code is not actually running.

Put a `.ToList()` on the end and it will run:

```
var result = words.OrderBy(a => a, new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).ToList();
```

You probably won't be able to step into the `.OrderBy()` call, but you will be able to put a breakpoint inside your comparer implementation.

Comment: could you explain the mechanism in a more better manner so that i could understand what went wrong

Comment: i was not able to debug even when i put a breakpoint inside the IComparer implementation

Comment: @LijinJohn https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2006/10/04/lazy-evaluation-and-in-contrast-eager-evaluation/ might help you to understand it better.

Comment: could you please see my update, so that you could understand my situation better

Comment: In that screenshot you don't have the `.ToList()` call after the `.OrderBy()`. Without that, the `.OrderBy()` won't be executed, and so your comparer won't be being called. Add it in and you should hit your breakpoint.

Comment: ok, after adding this it worked for me  
var result = words.OrderBy(a => a, new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).ToList();

Comment: @LijinJohn Any time you have an `IEnumerable<T>` and you haven't used the result -- whether by iterating in a `foreach` loop, calling `ToList()` etc.. -- it won't be evaluated. Think of `IEnumerable<T>` as promise that the items (If there are any) will be there when you need them. Keep in mind though that in the case that you have a an `IEnumerable<T>` that does something crazy to get its elements like, say, hitting a database, every time you iterate it will continually re-evaluate (read: hit your DB) its elements *unless* you call `ToList()`. Or only use it once ;)

Answer (score 0):

OrderBy returns an `IEnumrable` 
you to instate your Linq query , add `ToList()` after the `OrderBy` clause

```
 var result = words.OrderBy(a => a, new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).ToList();
```